# Javascript Google Chart Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-visualization, linechart

I am having issues creating a line chart for my website. Take a look at this link:

http://jsfiddle.net/asgallant/XdncE/

This works fine when I just have 12 arrays (1 entire year) in my inputData variable. However, when I try adding multiple years,

```
var inputData = [[1990,5335293],[1990,5309932],[1990,5327306],[1990,5354168],
[1990,5394006],[1990,5448990],[1990,5474112],[1990,5446876],[1990,5382558],
[1990,5410053], [1990,5399647],[1990,5386422],[1991,2780189],[1991,2785247],
[1991,2812202],[1991,2815125],[1991,2827592],[1991,2869426],[1991,2862056],
[1991,2822597],[1991,2806516],[1991,2815310],[1991,2806339],[1991,2792384]] ;
```

my graph completely messes up because the year intervals (haxis) become way off. Why is that? Do you guys know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to correct month calculation from

```
    var d = new Date(inputData[i][0], i, 1);
```

to

```
    var d = new Date(inputData[i][0], i%12, 1);
```